# Is it possible to call R functions and libraries in .Net framework

Tags: .net, winforms, r, user-interface

is their any possible way to call all the R packages/libraries and functions (packages like raster, rgdal, maptools etc.) in .net framework so that i am able to access all the features of R and run R script using .Net frontend....

Comment: The short answer is yes, use http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do R.NET supports raster data. If yes, does it have a raster processing library?

Comment: You can do image processing in R and in C# (or many other languages).  Decide what sort of image processing tasks you need to undertake, and try the Programmers Stack Exchange site for helping you choose a language.

Comment: Dear i have done image processing in 'R' i just want to create a front end in C#.net for that i have to call 'R' libraries and packages, for that purpose i was asking you which library will includes raster and rgdal package....

Comment: i have tried through R.NET and by calling R.NET.dll file in .net but still it is not supporting the Raster package in .net, if you could tell me the other way...

Comment: Start a new question, provide a small example of the code that you are trying to use, and explain the exact problem that you are having.  Then we can try to help.